# Partial mysqlbinlog on latest binlog file

Tags: mysql, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I'm trying to do a partial `mysqlbinlog` on the latest binary log file at a certain position therein (trying to extract just one query).

```
mysqlbinlog --start-position=1234 --stop-position=1234 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.000021
```

The output contains:

> Warning: this binlog is either in use or was not closed properly.

How do I force MySQL to start logging in the next binlog file (i.e. `mysql-bin.000022`) and release the original file so I can use `mysqlbinlog` it?

Is there another solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FLUSH LOGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html) to [rotate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-file-maintenance.html) the binlog before it reaches max size.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the position of the query in question, there's no reason you can't mysqlbinlog an open binlog. Sure you won't see anything that gets added to the log after you open it, but you can pipe it through less and search for the query.